# Remove duplicates from list and order it by count? (python 3)

Tags: code-golf, array, tips, counting, python

How do I remove all duplicates from list and order it based on count?

```
s = ["foo", "this", "lem", "foo", "lem"]
s = ["foo", "ebh", "wosv", "wosv", "ebh", "4whcu"]
#should return
>>> ["foo", "lem", "this"]
>>> ["ebh", "wosv", "foo", "4whcu"]
```

**Rules:**

- Must be shorter than the below code in terms of byte size.
- Order must be based on the count of  in descending order.
- If there are two strings with the same count, the first appearance comes first
- All duplicates must be removed, only one of each string should be in the final list

I currently have

```py
list({}.fromkeys(sorted(s,key=lambda y:-s.count(y))))
```

I've noticed answers like `set` but that arbitrarily changes the order, which I do not want.

**Edit:** Sorry for the poor quality before. I had whipped this right before I slept and I was quite tired. This is not for StackOverflow because I'm trying to golf/shorten the size of this code as much as possible. I've tried looking for answers but I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Do you mean "shorter in terms of byte count"?

Comment: Please add more information about the task and what you've tried. See https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18613/20260

Comment: This looks more like a stackoverflow question.

Comment: I've edited the question a bit.

Comment: I've added the relevant tags after you clarified, but please read through what xnor linked and the [tag:tips] tag description. There are a lot of things you haven't specified that are important to allow us to be able to golf this, e.g. version, precise IO requirements, tiebreaks in sorting, etc.

Comment: I've added some rules/criteria for golfing.

Comment: Looks almost good now, except that you didn't specify Python 2 or Python 3 (which are quite different in terms of golfing).

Comment: Oh..... that should have been obvious lol.

Comment: Does the solution have to be a single expression? Or can we include multiple statements?

Comment: @xnor Either, although I doubt you'd be able to get shorter with multiple statements.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 44 bytes

```python
sorted({}.fromkeys(s),key=s.count,reverse=1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcvBCoMwEATQu1@x5JRAEGJ7KuRLxEvthoTWrGSjIqXfnhrw4Okxw8y8Z0/xVtiAhV44IqFBZB@4@sGpcrY1DQ131yU@fWUjXq@e9X3z43J8GkcJGEKEno0G7oYHzCnEDLIwpYwv@f21LtH0xp0lK31ouR1piVknXDExWqOKKn8)

An improvement to the below, replacing the key with a built-in rather than a `lambda`, and using `reverse` to swap the comparisons. We'd like to do `[::-1]` on the final result instead, but that doesn't do the right stable tiebreaks.

We could also use `dict(zip(s,s))` in place of `{}.fromkeys(s)` for the same length.

---

## 47 bytes

```python
sorted({}.fromkeys(s),key=lambda y:-s.count(y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcvNCoMwEATgu0@xeEogFbQ9CT6JePAnIaEmK9lYCaXPnhrw4OljhpktBo3umaiGDvpSIZYCyqANZVdpM1eb01BQc1/KSWcOpM/dq34det7PT6HQA4Fx0FMtgJqhhc0bF4AlQh/kwr6/Snm0bxmJERen3TraaRkhtg@qZtxdYJHzxNMf)

A simple transposition of your code, moving your `{}.fromkeys` de-duplication trick before the sorting. Since sorting converts to a list, extracting the keys from a dictionary, this saves the `list()` call of the original.

For ease of reference, the original code is:

**53 bytes**

```python
list({}.fromkeys(sorted(s,key=lambda y:-s.count(y))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYvLCoMwFET3fsUlqwhW0HYl@CXiwkdCQpNcyY2VUPrtqQEXzuYwh5ktBoXumaiBHgYmEVkFLChNmUbYjMvmNhbU3pdiVhkH0ufOS78Oteznp5DogUA7GKipgNqxg81rF4Anoynw76@WHu1bROKEPoiVU3W23kx2XieI3YPqBXcXeCzPpDL9AQ)

Comment: [`sorted({}.fromkeys(s),key=s.count,reverse=1)`](https://tio.run/##TcvBCoMwEATQu1@x5JRAEGJ7KuRLxEvthoTWrGSjIqXfnhrw4Okxw8y8Z0/xVtiAhV44IqFBZB@4@sGpcrY1DQ131yU@fWUjXq@e9X3z43J8GkcJGEKEno0G7oYHzCnEDLIwpYwv@f21LtH0xp0lK31ouR1piVknXDExWqOKKn8) works as well at 44 bytes, since the `reverse` option doesn't just reverse the final output, but changes the actual sorting.

Comment: @ovs Nice find, was just posting the same

Comment: I'm curious though, why does s.count work in key?

Comment: @12944qwerty Consider `s.count` and `lambda x: s.count(x)` - I think you will see that they are identical :)

Comment: ohh, they both are functions and being called the same way....

Comment: @12944qwerty Exactly, see also [my tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95156/20260) for using object methods in golfing on this site.

Comment: Wouldn't `sorted({}.fromkeys(s),key=s.count)[::-1]` save 4 bytes?

Comment: @U12-F̉͋̅̾̇orward It's for the rule "If there are two strings with the same count, the first appearance comes first". The sorting is stable even with `reverse=1`, whereas reversing the output flips the order for ties.

Comment: @xnor Oh... Sorry.. Didn't see that...

Answer (score 0):

**APL, 11 chars**

`∪⌷⍨∘⊂∘⍒⊢∘≢⌸`

`⊢∘≢⌸` right arg: number of apperance of each element, in order of first appearance

`∪`             left arg: unique elements, in order of first appearance`

`⌷⍨∘⊂∘⍒`      sorts elements of the left arg based on the grade-down of the right arg`

Try it online: https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v9jwUdsE9bT8fHUF9ZKMzGIglZOaCyQhQiA2V7ERQk1qUgaQLM8vLkNQEDGT8ozkUnUurjSg4kcdqx71bH/Uu@JRx4xHXU0gsnfSo65FIEbnokc9O7i4HvVNBSpMUyg2RDCN/v8HAA

Comment: It’s not quite python.

Comment: Ooops, sorry, I thought it was, like the other challenges, something to be done in the language of choice.